# CPPZMQ - Publish and subscribe with standard vector

Tags: c++, c++17, zeromq

From the documentation at: https://brettviren.github.io/cppzmq-tour/index.html#intro, it seems that it is possible with CPPZMQ to send and receive a standard vector by using messages or buffers. However, I have not been able to use the vector from the subscriber, I get an error when trying to access it:

```
Segmentation error (core dumped)
```

when I run the following code:

Publisher:

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <zmq.hpp>
    #include <thread>
    using namespace std;
    using namespace zmq;

    int main()
    {
        vector<float> v(2, 0.0);
        context_t ctx;
        socket_t pub(ctx, ZMQ_PUB);
        const std::string addr = "tcp://127.0.0.1:5678";
        pub.bind(addr);

        while (true)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
            v = {0.1, 0.2};
            message_t msg(v);
            auto res = pub.send(msg, send_flags::none);
            cout << "message sent" << endl;
        }
    }
```

Subscriber:

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <zmq.hpp>
    using namespace std;
    using namespace zmq;

    int main()
    {
        context_t ctx;
        socket_t sub(ctx, socket_type::sub);
        const std::string addr = "tcp://127.0.0.1:5678";
        sub.set(zmq::sockopt::subscribe, "");
        sub.connect(addr);
        message_t msg;
        const vector<float>* iptr = msg.data<vector<float>>();

        while (true)
        {
            if (sub.recv(msg, zmq::recv_flags::none))
            {
                cout << "msg received" << endl;
                iptr = msg.data<vector<float>>();
                cout << "iptr: " << iptr << endl;
                cout << "element 0: " << (*iptr)[0] << "endl";
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is:

How do I retrieve the vector in the publisher ? More generally, with a vector of constant length and type, I would need an efficient way to send and receive such vector, for example avoiding copy and avoiding reallocation and destruction at every message. What is the recommended way to do that ?

Comment: What those 2 statements are supposed to achieve: `const vector<float>* iptr = msg.data<vector<float>>();`, and then `iptr = msg.data<vector<float>>();` ?

Comment: I mostly used the documentation mentioned in the question (see "Accessing data in a message"). I suppose these two lines are used to declare a pointer then cast from void* to the correct type ?

Comment: Hmm oki. I don't think you can use it like that. To construct the message by passing `std::vector` might be ok, because https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/blob/master/zmq.hpp#L473 it will just use iterator constructor and copy the vector memory. However `data<T>()` https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/blob/master/zmq.hpp#L602 just invokes `static_cast`, which might be ok for trivial types, but not for a `std::vector` which is a complex class.

Comment: So, I probably extrapolated too far the documentation. What would be the recommended solution then (efficiency wise), a structure containing the vector ?

Comment: Construct your vector from the received bytes. `std::vector<float> vec; vec.resize(msg.size()/sizeof(float))` and then copy the bytes `memcpy(vec.data(), msg.data(), msg.size());`. Note that `msg.size()` must be dividable by float size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructing `zmq::message_t` directly from STL vector is ok, because [iterator based constructor](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/blob/v4.8.1/zmq.hpp#L480) will be called.

```
std::vector<float> v({0.1, 0.2});
message_t msg(v);
```

It will internally copy the content of the vector to the underlying `zmq_msg_data` casted to `float*`:

```
std::copy(first, last, data<value_t>());  // value_t == float in this case
```

However, [templated version](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/blob/v4.8.1/zmq.hpp#L602) of `message_t::data` method

```
template<typename T> T *data() ZMQ_NOTHROW { return static_cast<T *>(data()); }
```

is just a static cast from `void*` to your `T*`. So if you invoke it like that: `msg.data<vector<float>>();` you try to cast raw buffer to complex `std::vector` class, which is incorrect. Instead, you can copy received raw data to newly created float vector:

```
std::vector<float> vec;
vec.resize(msg.size()/sizeof(float));  // note that msg size must be divisible by float size
std::memcpy(vec.data(), msg.data(), msg.size());
```

Alternatively you can get already casted data `float* rawData = msg.data<float>();` and use

```
std::copy(rawData, rawData+msg.size()/sizeof(float), std::back_inserter(vec));
```